# Problem with Tainted canvases in Angular Native Element

Tags: typescript, canvas, cors, angular9

I have recently been experimenting with ***CANVAS***, *(so I am a newbie)*, and now I work in an application where I draw images on a canvas and then store the result.

My problem is that when I try to edit a **canvas** by **drawing** on the images that come from a different **domain** than my app I get the **error**.

```
Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
```

When i try to run this

```
this.ctx.canvas.toDataURL()
```

> am using typescript in angular 9

My purpose with this is to convert the **canvas** into an **image** to *store* it.

I had read in some results on the internet that it could be solved in this way
[source](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1614#issuecomment-452954093)

```
html2canvas (document.body, {
    allowTaint: true,
    foreignObjectRendering: true
});
```

But since I am using **native element** with **angular** I don't know what the "*equivalent*" is for this implementation.

```
@ViewChild('previewHeroMaker', {static: true}) heroMakerPreviewCanvas: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;

this.ctx = this.heroMakerPreviewCanvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
```

So I *understand* that I have to find a way to add the `allowTaint` property to my canvas with my current `code`, if anyone has any opinion that can shed light on this it would be great.

Answer (score -1):

Well for anyone who is having this trouble I notice that the problem with tainted canvases is that when you try to use out same domain images or resources, the local drive generates this error for security.
Anyway am using an **image** so only add a *property* `crossOrigin`  to the image and works perfectly.

```
      const baseImage = new Image();
      baseImage.src = imageUrl;
      baseImage.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
```

you can see more information about this here [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image)